# How to perform web scraping for TOSS SSC results using python and selenium

Tags: python, html, css, forms, selenium-chromedriver

Web scraping with student roll numbers to get TOSS SSC results is useful for collecting student results by entering hall ticket or admission number. what are the possible solutions. please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from splinter import Browser

browser = Browser('chrome', headless=True)
browser.visit('http://resultsjun.telanganaopenschool.org/TOSSRESULTSssc.aspx')
fruits = [20221511001]

for x in fruits:
    y=x+100
    for n in range(x, y):
        browser.fill('tbHTNo', n)
        browser.find_by_name('btnSubmit').click()
        with open('NAMESTOSS511.txt', 'a') as f:
            if browser.is_element_present_by_id('lblCName'):
                text= browser.find_by_css('#lblCName').value;
                f.write(text)
                f.writelines(' ')
                TEXT2=browser.find_by_css('#lblAdmnno').value;
                f.write(TEXT2)
                f.writelines("\n")
            else:
                f.writelines("NA\n")
                continue
```

Comment: you need python and selenium chrome driver installed for this.